# Random php session loss on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I have a first file `file1.php` on my server which creates a session variable and displays it (I leave this file open).

http://localhost/file1.php :

```
session_start();       
$_SESSION['test'] = "hello";    
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

I have a second `file2.html` file on my PC (not on my server) which contains a form pointing to a third file  `file3.php` on my server which displays the previously created session variable.

file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/file2.html :

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/file3.php">    
         
    <input type="submit" >GO 
     
 </form>
```

http://localhost/file3.php :

```
session_start();     
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

When I click on the `file2.html` submit button, everything goes well on Firefox, the `file3.php` file is launched and the session variable is displayed, but on Chrome the display is random and sometimes the PHPSESSID cookie is renewed and I lose the session variable and I get the following message:

**Warning**: Undefined array key "test" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\momo\file3.php**

Why does this work on Chrome and not on Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research I have an answer. For this to work on Chrome as on Firefox, you must add these 2 lines before `session_start();`:
`ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1); ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');`

And if you want this to never work, you have to add this line:
`ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Lax');`

This attribute is a way to mitigate CSRF attacks.